# trouble integrating a jQuery dynamic search dropdown with ability for multiple selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am integrating a search function that will dynamically populate a drop down menu with the contents in a database. With that said however, when one option from the drop down is clicked I want the search function to "reset" itself such that another option can be selected thereby having 2 or more possible selections in the input box. for example, here is the desired output:

[image]

At the moment the code below only allows for the dynamic dropdown list to be generated once:

```
jQuery(".search").keyup(function() {
        var searchbox = jQuery(this).val();
        var dataString = 'searchword='+ searchbox;

        if(searchbox==''){
            jQuery("#display").hide();
        } else {

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/inbox/user-search/",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html)
                {   jQuery("#display").html(html).show();

                    jQuery("li").click(function(){ 

                        jQuery("#send-message-to-user").val(jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).text())+"; ");

                        jQuery("#display").hide();
                    })

                }
            });
        } return false;    

    });
```

There is something I am missing obviously... any help would be greatly appreciated... cheers

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Bit difficult when the HTML isn't in here as well. Does this get you on your way?:

```
function getTextBehindLastSemicolon(string) {
    if (string.match(/\;\ (.*)$/)[0]){
        return string.match(/\;\ (.*)$/)[0];
    }
    else{
        // If no semicolons
        return string;
    }

}

var isLoading=false;
function autocomplete(searchWord) {
    if (isLoading){
        return;
    }
    isLoading=true;

    var dataString = 'searchword=' + searchWord;

    if (searchWord == '') {
        jQuery("#display").hide();
    } else {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/inbox/user-search/",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                jQuery("#display").html(html).show();

                jQuery("li").click(function() {
                    jQuery("#send-message-to-user").val(jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).text()) + "; ");
                    jQuery("#display").hide();
                });
                isLoading=false;

            }
        });
    }
    return false;
}

jQuery(".search").keyup(function() {
    autocomplete(getTextBehindLastSemicolon(jQuery(this).val()));
    return false;
});
```

Comment: looks possible... but the console is spitting out the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null VM2292:51
getTextBehindLastSemicolon VM2292:51
(anonymous function) VM2292:98
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.10.2.js:5095
elemData.handle